# 'float' object is not iterable error

Tags: python, xml, list, floating-point

I am trying to get a a variable that reads out a load value (given in xml document) for a given length of a time (also a list of values). The list for t is from a value 'start' to 'end' with an interval of 15 min. Essentially what I want is that I want one load value to print for the entire length of its respective time list. So if its time list is [0 15 30 45 60] then I want its load value to be in a list repeating 5 times. The xml document and code I am running are below and I keep getting an error with my potW assignment saying "'float' object is not iterable." I know this is a lot but any suggestions?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
import os

class WaterModel:

    def __init__(self,fn):

        self.tree = ET.parse(fn)
        self.root = self.tree.getroot()

        self.title, self.start, self.end, self.load, self.duration, self.Type = [],[],[],[],[],[]

        for child in self.root:
            self.title.append(child.find('title').text)

            sh = int(child.find('startHour').text)
            sm = int(child.find('startMinute').text)
            self.duration.append(int(child.find('duration').text))
            self.start.append(sh*60+sm)
            self.end.append(self.start[-1] + self.duration[-1])
            self.Type.append(child.find('Type').text)
            self.load.append(float(child.find('load').text))


    def Wp(self):

        greyW = 0  
        for i in range(len(self.root)):
            if self.Type[i] == 'greywater':
                greyW += self.load[i]*self.duration[i]

        t = range(self.start[i], self.end[i]+1, 15)  
        for i in range(len(self.root)):
            for j in range(len(t)):
                if self.Type[i] == 'potable':
                    potW = [a for a in self.load[j]]

fn = 'SD2017NominalWaterUse.xml'
a = WaterModel(fn)
b = a.Wp()
print(b)
```

xml file 'SD2017NominalWaterUse.xml' that is read into the code above:

```
<WaterNominalDay>

<event>
<title>Evening Washer</title>
<Type>greywater</Type>
<startHour>19</startHour>
<startMinute>30</startMinute>
<duration units = 'min'>270</duration>
<load units = 'gal/min'>.051852</load>
<comment>
''
</comment>
</event> 

<event>
<title>Morning Cooking</title>
<Type>potable</Type>
<startHour>7</startHour>
<startMinute>30</startMinute>
<duration units = 'min'>180</duration>
<load units = 'gal/min'>.003331</load>
<comment>
'5 lb water is .5995 gal'
</comment> 
</event>

<event>
<title>Evening Cooking</title>
<Type>potable</Type>
<startHour>19</startHour>
<startMinute>30</startMinute>
<duration units = 'min'>180</duration>
<load units = 'gal/min'>.003331</load>
<comment>
'5 lb water is .5995 gal'
</comment> 
</event>


<event>
<title>Leaks</title>
<Type>potable</Type>
<startHour>0</startHour>
<startMinute>00</startMinute>
<duration units = 'min'>1440</duration>
<load units = 'gal/min'>.006944</load>
<comment>
''
</comment> 
</event>

</WaterNominalDay>
```

Comment: Isn't `[a for a in X]` just a shallow copy of `X`?  Wouldn't `X[:]` accomplish the same thing (if that is what you are trying to do)?

Answer (score 0):

`self.load` i an array of `float`s, so `self.load[j]` will be a float, which is what you are trying to iterate over; hence the error message.

Comment: Yes self.load has 4 values but I want those values to repeat for the length of its respective time list. I am trying to iterate the single load value over its respective time but for the four different instances. Is this the incorrect method for doing it?

Comment: Clearly it is incorrect; as I am not clear on what you are trying to do, I can't say what you should do instead.  Maybe if you *showed* what result you wanted in your example, instead of just describing it.